# 500 internal server error within my mvc project

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm developing a mvc project but when I run my index.php file it is giving me Internal Server Error.

My code is as following:

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

index.php

```
<?php
echo $_GET['url'];
?>
```

I'm using wampserver php 5.4.16.

Kindly help me.

Comment: And nothing in the error_log file?

Comment: Is the module `mod_rewrite` installed and activated?

Comment: ya nothing in the error_log file.

Comment: i activated rewrite_module but i'm getting error Undefined index: url.

Comment: Make sure if your `.htaccess` is enabled by putting same garbage text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not?